# What part of speech is foaming acting as?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Foaming waves crashed against the wall.

Comment: Related if not actually a duplicate: [Is *running* a gerund or a participial adjective?](/q/366906)

Comment: Probably a verb phrase.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest analysis is that "foaming" is a participle of a verb, modifying the noun "waves".

There are various "tests" of whether something is an adjective or not - but I'm not sure how useful these tests are. There are lots of things that can modify a noun: participles, adjectives, nouns etc. But the mere fact that tests are needed indicates that the answer can't be decided from the sentence as it is written, but only by considering modifications of the sentence (eg can the word take an object? can the word be graded?)  And anyway to run these tests you need native speaker intuition of grammar, so they are fairly useless for non-native speakers.

So does it matter?  The word "foaming" modifies the word waves.  We understand the meaning (the waves form or produce foam). Does it really matter if it is an participle or participial adjective?

Answer (score 0):

English you can use:

**foaming** waves = waves that are foaming
**erupting** volcanoes = volcanoes that are erupting
**rampaging** bulls  = bulls that are rampaging
**crying** babies   = babies that are crying

In English, you can take many action verbs and use them as adjectives. These are also used as nouns.  For example: Foaming is important for certain soaps.